# PyTorch: Variable data has to be a tensor -- data is already as tenors

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, torch, pytorch

I am trying to load data using pytorch's Dataset and DataLoader classes. I use `torch.from_numpy`to convert each array to a tensor in the torch Dataset and from looking into the data, each X and y is indeed a tensor

```
# At this point dataset is {'X': numpy array of arrays, 'y': numpy array of arrays  } 

class TorchDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset):
        self.X_train = torch.from_numpy(dataset['X'])
        self.y_train = torch.from_numpy(dataset['y'])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X_train)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return {'X': self.X_train[index], 'y': self.y_train[index]}

torch_dataset = TorchDataset(dataset)
dataloader = DataLoader(torch_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)


for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for X, y in enumerate(dataloader):
        features = Variable(X)
        labels = Variable(y)
        ....
```

However on `features = Variable(X)` i get:

```
RuntimeError: Variable data has to be a tensor, but got int
```

An example of an X and y in the dataset are:

```
In [1]: torch_dataset[1]
Out[1]: 
{'X': 
 -2.5908 -3.1123 -2.9460  ...  -3.9898 -4.0000 -3.9975
 -3.0867 -2.9992 -2.5254  ...  -4.0000 -4.0000 -4.0000
 -2.7665 -2.5318 -2.7035  ...  -4.0000 -4.0000 -4.0000
       ...             ⋱             ...          
 -2.4784 -2.6061 -1.6280  ...  -4.0000 -4.0000 -4.0000
 -2.2046 -2.1778 -1.5626  ...  -3.9597 -3.9366 -3.9497
 -1.9623 -1.9468 -1.5352  ...  -3.8485 -3.8474 -3.8474
 [torch.DoubleTensor of size 1024x1024], 'y': 
  107
 [torch.LongTensor of size 1]}
```

which is why it is very confusing for me that torch thinks X is an int. Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is error in your use of [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which caused the error because the first return value of `enumerate` is the batch index, not the actual data. There are two ways you can make your script work.

## First way

Since your `X` and `y` is do not need special process. You can just return a sample of `X` and `y`. Change your `__getitem__` method to

```
 def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.X_train[index], self.y_train[index]
```

Also, change your training loop a little bit:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):    
    for batch_id, (x, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
           x = Variable(x)
           y = Variable(y)
           # then do whatever you want to do
```

## Second way

You can return a dict in the `__getitem__` method and extract the actual data in the training loop. In this case, you do not need to change the `__getitem__` method. Just change your training loop:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):    
    for batch_id, data in enumerate(dataloader):
        # data will be dict 
        x = Variable(data['X'])
        y = Variable(data['y'])
        # then do whatever you want to do
```

Comment: In the DataLoader example you linked, the `__getitem__` method actually returns a dict too:

`sample = {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks}`.

When the DataLoader is enumerated you can explicitly unpack the dictionary (I actually mistyped that in my initial post). Thanks!

Comment: see the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are using enumerate in the for-loop. So, what you are doing is the following

```
for batch_index, batch in enumerate(dataloader):
```